# Say we have an abstract data type for cities. A city has a name, a latitude coordinate, and a longitude coordinate

Tags: scheme, racket, abstraction

Our data abstraction has one constructor:

```
(make-city name lat lon)
```

Creates a city object with the given name, latitude, and longitude.
We also have the following selectors in order to get the information for each city:

```
(get-name city)   ;; Returns the city's name
(get-lat city)    ;; Returns the city's latitude
(get-lon city)    ;; Returns the city's longitude
```

My code:

```
(define (make-city name lat lon)
  (cons name (cons lat (cons lon null))))

(define (get-name make-city)
  (car make-city))

(define (get-lat make-city)
  (car (cdr make-city)))

(define (get-lon make-city)
  (cdr (cdr make-city)))

(define berkeley (make-city 'Berkeley 122 37))
(get-name berkeley)    'Berkeley
(get-lat berkeley)     122
(get-lon berkeley)     '(37)
```

The problem is that the result of `(get-lon berkeley)` is `'(37)` but i want the output to be `37`, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, if you have `'(37)`, how would you obtain `37`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Racket, you should use [a structure](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html) instead of a list to represent the city. The default function names created by `struct` don't match yours, so you can make aliases (Or use the struct-generated ones directly):

```lisp
(struct city (name lat lon)
  #:transparent
  #:extra-constructor-name make-city)
(define get-name city-name)
(define get-lat city-lat)
(define get-lon city-lon)
```

That gives you more efficient storage space and access time compared to a list, gives you `city?` to easily test if a value is a city, and the only way `get-lon` will return a list is if you create the city with a list instead of a number for the longitude (And there are ways to prevent that mistake, too, like a `#:guard` clause or [struct contracts](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/data-structure-contracts.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fstruct-dc..rkt%29._struct%2Fc%29%29))

If your list-based layout is a requirement of an assignment and can't be changed, though, you might consider list access functions like [`first`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._first%29%29). Easier to remember than figuring the correct chain of `car`s and `cdr`s.

Answer (score 4):

With your definitions, `(make-city 'Berkeley 122 37)` produces this structure:

[image: Berkeley]

Each node is a pair, and in this structure:

- `car` picks the thing the left-hand arrow points at (going down the way this has been drawn);
- `cdr` picks the thing the right hand arrow points at.

So `(cdr (cdr (make-city 'Berkeley 122 37)))` follows two right-pointing arrows to return this object:

[image: Broken]

Which prints as `(37)`.

I think it should be clear by looking at these diagrams how you need to fix this problem.  There are at least two ways: one is better than the other.

(For added points: why are representations like this not good in general?)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you are making an object with two values. You could just `cons` them so that `(make-object a b)` does `(cons a b)`. Then `object-a` would be `car` and `object-b` would be `cdr`. This is the most efficient.

Your solution uses proper list and the proper list version of the two value object is `(list a b)` or `(cons a (cons b '()))` which makes the first accessor the same, but the last would be `cadr` instead of `cdr` and there is always an empty list that is never used.

You can solve this either by making your object more efficient like my first example, or by keeping your solution and using the proper accessor. Your choice!